# What is Youtube.com trying to have me download when I go to this URL in firefox?

Tags: youtube

If you go to this youtube video's page using firefox (Windows: 48.0.2), it asks you to download an octet stream.

> http://www.youtube.com/v/yW3gunMSCu4

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser is attempting to download a compressed flash object and adobe flash i'snt installed.

CWS within the header of the stream is a clear indication of this behavior.

Source: http://www.m2osw.com/swf_tag_file_header